# Phantomjs Alternative - RFC6455 WebSocket Standard required

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, headless-browser, rfc6455

Unit Testing javascript frontend with phantomjs however the websockets unable to authenticate (401) requests. Did some research found that Phantomjs using older Webkit with older standard. What Alternative headless browser could I use instead of Phantomjs with the latest Websocket Standards?

Comment: Did you find an alternative for Phantomjs that works with WebSockets?

Answer (score 0):

http://slimerjs.org/ has the same API and can be run headlessly with [xvfb](http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs). It runs the gecko engine through your installed firefox. So you will have web socket support.

There is also http://triflejs.org/ with the same PhantomJS API, but is not yet done/feature complete.