# how to capture and test for socket.io events in casper.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, casperjs

I'm using Casperjs to test a socket.io application.  I want the ability to assert that different emits have happened, from the server and the client, but the code I have below keeps giving me errors.

I have the following line in my test setup:

```
casper.page.injectJs('test_include.js');
```

test_include.js looks like:

```
document.emits = [];
document.ons = [];
(function(){
    var _origEmit = main_socket.emit;
    main_socket.emit = function(){
        console.log("SENT", Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        document.emits.push(arguments);
        _origEmit.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
    var _origOn = main_socket.$emit;
    main_socket.$emit = function(){
        console.log("RECEIVED", Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        document.ons.push(arguments);
        _origOn.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
    console.log("Injection complete");
})();
```

The injection complete runs, so I know the injectjs is working.  Then, in my test case where I check to see if it's working at all:

```
casper.evaluate(function(){
    main_socket.emit('testin');
    console.log("EMITS", JSON.stringify(document.emits));
});
```

and the output shows basically that there haven't been any emits, even though I just emitted something:

```
EMITS [{}]
```

For my end goal I'd like the ability to click a link, assert that the proper socket.io event is emitted, wait 500ms and assert that the server has emitted what I would expect to see back.  It seems like this would be an every day use case but I'm having troubles getting the full cycle working.

(note, in my update, I found the error that was happening and it was elsewhere, so I updated to show what isn't working stead of the error)

Comment: Please register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. Maybe there are errors. If you are using phantomjs as the engine in casper, then it probably doesn't work because [PhantomJS doesn't support websockets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25182226/1816580). If the events should still work even though the websockets are not working, you will need to post more code. Look at SlimerJS for an alternative CasperJS engine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

In my test_include.js file I was pushing onto the array incorrectly.

```
document.emits.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
```

Not sure why I was just pushing arguments without slicing it, but that wasn't working.